# Electron: Security concern regarding inline styles in an iframe

Tags: iframe, electron

Question: I'm trying to load an external script (let's say from example.com) in the Electron app. The External script loads everything in an iframe and it's using inline styles, which renders the widget without any styles due to Electron CSP. I don't want to use unsafe-inline CSP on the whole application, I need it just on this iframe which comes from "example.com".

Error which I get: Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'"

For resolving this I am thinking to add this code block in my electron app -

```
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
    if(details.url.includes("example.com") && details.url.includes(".html")) {
      callback({
      responseHeaders: Object.assign({

        "Content-Security-Policy": [ "default-src 'self';style-src 'unsafe-inline' https://*.example.com https://example.com" ]
    }, details.responseHeaders)});
    }
```

This code block will ensure to have 'unsafe-inline' CSP only in the iframes of "abc.com". But, I want to check that can this code block still cause any kind of security threat to my app?

Answer (score 0):

Does your iframe contain any user entered data? If not then this is fine. If it does then you will need to find another way to check they have not entered any inline styles